# Downloading a stored PDF gets damaged

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working in a Web in .Net Core with MVC. I want to download a PDF from my database in SQL Server. I save the PDF in my database in *varbinary*, and in the controller, I get the PDF in `byte[]`.

But when I download the PDF from my web I want to see the PDF. Said the PDF is damaged.

This is the method to download the PDF in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileContentResult DownloadFile(string DNI)
{
    Byte[] file1 = _manager.SetFile1(DNI);

    Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=dddddd.pdf");
    return new FileContentResult(file1,"application/pdf");
}
```

This is the code when i insert the PDF to the controller, and after i save in the SQL Server with *varbinary* type:

```
var reader2 = new StreamReader(certificateCompany.OpenReadStream());

string contentAsString2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();

byte[] contentAsByteArray2 = GetBytes(contentAsString2);
```

certificateCompany is a IFormFile type. He come from here:

```
<input type="file" name="attachedWorking1" id="attachedWorking1" accept=".pdf" multiple />
```

After,in my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FormCause(IFormFile attachedWorking1)
       {
        var certificateCompany = attachedWorking1;

        var reader1 = new StreamReader(certificateCompany.OpenReadStream());

        string contentAsString1 = reader1.ReadToEnd();

        byte[] contentAsByteArray1 = GetBytes(contentAsString1);

        petition.file1 = contentAsByteArray1;

        _manager.InsertPetition(petition);

            return View("Close");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because the code saving the PDF to the database is incorrect.

You are saving a string not a PDF.

Do not use a stream reader in this case. It is for text.

Instead [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) the bytes directly from the stream returned when `certificateCompany.OpenReadStream()` is called.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> FormCause(IFormFile attachment) {
    var certificateCompany = attachment;

    var stream = certificateCompany.OpenReadStream();

    var length =  (int)stream.Length;

    byte[] data = new byte[length];

    await stream.ReadAsync(buffer: data, offset: 0, count: length);

    //...

    petition.file1 = data;

    _manager.InsertPetition(petition);

    return View("Close");
}
```